# How do I test if a floating point number is an integer in haskell?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, integer

If I have a floating point number in Haskell how do I test if it is a whole number.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
isInt x = x == fromInteger (round x)

> isInt 2
True
> isInt 2.5
False
```

And just a reminder: always remember the almighty curse of the floating point numbers:

```
> isInt (0.1^2*200)
False
> 0.1^2*200
2.0000000000000004
```

Comment: @Peter: no, according to Hoogle.

Comment: Be aware that `isInt (1/0) == True`

Comment: @hvr: interesting, that's very strange

Answer (score 20):

Okay, so this is a year late, but I'm a big fan of a modification of the above:

```
--Returns if x is an int to n decimal places
isInt :: (Integral a, RealFrac b) => b -> a -> Bool
isInt x n = (round $ 10^(fromIntegral n)*(x-(fromIntegral $ round x)))==0
```

So, for instance `isInt 4.0001 3` returns `True` but `isInt 4.0001 4` returns `False`.  Running it with a value around `10` is almost always accurate enough that float-errors will be what gives your problems again; I usually use `7`.

Comment: I find `isInt :: (Integral a, RealFrac b) => a -> b -> Bool` with
`isInt n x = round (10 ^ fromIntegral n * (x - fromIntegral (round x))) == 0` a little more composable and easy to read.